# Deleting a pointer in a list causing memory leak

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

So I have a program (a game but the question in c++ question) which has a Character class.  This is simplified code of the classes/methods in question

eg

BaseCharacter.h

```
class BaseCharacter
{
    BaseCharacter();
    ~BaseCharacter();

    Weapon* m_currentWeapon;
    DoubleLinkedList<Weapon*> m_weaponsHeld;
}
```

BaseCharacter.cpp

```
BaseCharacter::BaseCharacter()
{
    m_currentWeapon = new Weapon();
    m_weaponsHeld.Insert(m_currentWeapon);
}
BaseCharacter::~BaseCharacter()
{
    m_weaponsHeld.Clear();
}
```

The idea of this class is that every character starts with one starting weapon (which is added to the list of weapons) and also can hold mulitple weapons (which when created are stored through the List)

The List functions for Insert and Clear are like this

```
template <class C>
inline void
DoubleLinkedList<C>::Insert(const C &Data)
{
    LinkedListNode<C>* node = new LinkedListNode<C>(Data);

    if(m_tail)
    {
        m_tail->SetNext(node);
        node->SetPrevious(m_tail);
        m_tail = node;
    }
    else
    {
        m_head = node;
        m_tail = node;
    }
  listSize++;
}


template <class C>
inline void
DoubleLinkedList<C>::Clear()
{
    LinkedListNode<C>* entry = m_head;

    while (entry)
    {
        LinkedListNode<C>* release = entry;
        entry = entry->GetNext();
        delete release;
    }

    listSize = 0;
    m_head = 0;
    m_tail = 0;
}
```

The issue I am having is that when the BaseCharacters class is deleted, the destructor is called and a memory leak occurs.

I don't really understand (well I have a small idea - think I am deleting a pointer to a pointer when I clear the list rather than the object stored in the list) why the Weapon classes destructor isn't called when the lists Clear() function is called in the BaseCharacters destructor.

Can someone show me the logic error in cleaning up the list and weapons of the character?

Comment: use a `std::shared_ptr` ...

Comment: You are deleting the LinkedListNode, but is that destructor deleting the weapon?

Comment: @Colin Ah so is Clear() just deleting all the nodes pointers in the list rather than actually calling delete on what each node points to?

Comment: Clear is deleting the node, but a node isn't a weapon right?  You need to delete the weapon the node points to, and then delete the node.  But in reality, using something like `shared_ptr` would be best so the delete happens automatically. when all the pointers to an object are gone.

Comment: @unknownSPY Correct. In the destructor for LinkedListNode you need to find a way to delete the thing its containing. Also: you should probably make ~BaseCharacter virtual.

Comment: @Colin  Thanks.  I guess I can just loop through the list calling delete on each Weapon in the list (which would clean up the actual objects in the list) before calling Clear()?

Answer (score 0):

Are you really having a memory-*leak* or *corruption*? I could think of a *corruption* because you delete the weapon and in case a second player has the same pointer to the weapon `DoubleLinkedList<C>::Clear` tries to free the memory again of the same object.

Removing `delete` might work here but that's not the final solution. Someone has to `own` the actual weapon - probably the game-engine which creates the asset and assigns them to the individual characters. But why do all characters share the same instance? Shouldn't each player own his own copy of the weapon? I would expect the weapon has an individual ammo count and this shouldn't be shared :)

Therefore each player should own his own weapon.

Comment: Hi, sorry maybe I wasn't clear in my slimmed down example.  the List of weapons is not a global list so no two characters would have a pointer to the same weapon.  Each character has their own list.  and as you correctly said.  Some one has to `own` the weapon.  currently its the character.  I guess I want a method that actually deletes all the Weapons in the list rather than just the nodes of the list

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. So in your example you just delete the instance of `LinkedListNode` but the weapon seems to remain in memory. If your character owns the weapon you should browse the list and delete the weapon before you clear the list (e.g. via `delete node->data;` or however you can access it). If your linked-list actually owns the weapon you should delete the object in `DoubleLinkedList<C>::Clear()`.

Comment: OK, so I think possibly the best solution is to first call something like `delete node->Data` and then call the `DoubleLinkedList<C>::Remove()` function on that node which removes (tidily) the node from the list then deletes the node?

Comment: Yes, that would be one way. It depends if you want that `DoubleLinkedList` owns the objects or if just acts as a list.

Comment: The only problem I can for see with having the list own the objects is if a list was created iwth objects that aren't created with `new` if would fail when trying to delete something that wasn't an object?  or is that wrong